# Why and how is MVC request thread state maintained after await on a MVC controller action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

In following code, thread id's and hashes of _uow (unit of work) are the same before and after the call to await.  If the request thread is released, why does the continuation request thread have the same id?  Why does the _uow object associated with the request thread have the same hash id like thread state is maintained although it was released into the thread pool?

```
public AccountController(IUow uow)
{
    _uow = uow;
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Sample()
{
    int id1 = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    int hash1 = _uow.GetHashCode();

    await SignInAsync(account, isPersistent: false);

    int id2 = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId; //same as id1
    int hash2 = _uow.GetHashCode(); //same as hash1

    return Content("");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET, you're not guaranteed to be on the the same thread after an `await`. But that doesn't mean you are guaranteed to be on another thread, you could still return to the same thread by chance. And you will also stay on the same thread if the `Task` you're `await`ing has already completed when it's returned to you.

But the `_uow` field is a different matter: that will always stay the same in this code (assuming it's not a `[ThreadStatic]` field). That's because after `await`, you always return to the same `this`, that's not tied to any thread.

Actually, this is even stronger: the `HttpContext.Current` (and everything associated with it) will *also* stay the same. That's because the ASP.NET synchronization context will take care of moving the HTTP context to any new thread after `await`.

Answer (score 1):

Two scenarios are possible here.

- `SignInAsync` has executed synchronously. Try the following to see if that's the case:

  ```
  public async Task<ActionResult> Sample()
  {
      int id1 = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
      int hash1 = _uow.GetHashCode();

      var task = SignInAsync(account, isPersistent: false);
      Debug.Print("completed synchronously: " + task.IsCompleted);
      await task;    

      int id2 = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId; //same as id1
      int hash2 = _uow.GetHashCode(); //same as hash1

      return Content("");
  }
  ```
- The same pool thread is happened to serve the rest of the request after the `await` continuation. It is very unlikely, but still possible, although you should never rely upon this anyway.

Comment: Seems like it has to do with synchronization context.  I'm going to read these articles.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx

Comment: @Clive, `AspNetSynchronizationContext` doesn't enforce thread affinity, rather vice verse. Make sure you use [`UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975440.aspx).